# How to set up ErrorHadler via application.ini?

Tags: zend-framework, configuration, config, zend-application

I set up default `errorHandler` in `Bootstrap.php` this way:

```
public function _initErrorHandler()
{
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $plugin = new Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler(
        array(
            'module' => 'default',
            'controller' => 'error',
            'action' => 'error'
    ));
    $frontController->registerPlugin($plugin);

    return $plugin;
}
```

How can I make the same via `application.ini` options?

Comment: isnt the errorhandler active by default?

Comment: @ArneRie Yes, it is. But in the default module. I need an easy way to change it, when I set other module as the default one.

Comment: Look at: https://github.com/codeinchaos/restful-zend-framework#module-specific-errorcontroller-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "automatically" I don't think it's possible, since the ErrorHandler plugin isn't a resource plugin.

But, if you want to bootstrap your own personal error handler, you can do something like this:

in your application.ini:

```
errorhandler.class = "Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler"
errorhandler.options.module = default
errorhandler.options.controller = error
errorhandler.options.action = error
```

And, in your bootstrap to load these options:

```
public function _initErrorHandler()
{
    // make sure the frontcontroller has been setup
    $this->bootstrap('frontcontroller');
    $frontController = $this->getResource('frontcontroller');
    // option from the config file
    $pluginOptions   = $this->getOption('errorhandler');
    $className       = $pluginOptions['class'];

    // I'm using zend_loader::loadClass() so it will throw exception if the class is invalid.
    try {
        Zend_Loader::loadClass($className);
        $plugin          = new $className($pluginOptions['options']);
        $frontController->registerPlugin($plugin);
        return $plugin;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // do something useful here (like fall back to the default error handler)
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's something I already do, but I was looking the way to skip the code in Bootstrap.